# How to extract unstructured excel file data(dashboard data) and export it to as structured clean data

Tags: python, excel, automation

I have a lots of excel files that has data in dashboard presenting form and i want this data to be read in python in structured manner like each column of data in excel file represent a column of data in pandas column.

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_excel('claim.xls',index=None,error_bad_lines=False)
df
```

when i run this code i get the following output:
[image]

Is there any other approach in python to get all the data in code?

Comment: ad link to you excel file

Comment: here please. https://drive.google.com/file/d/19DMr0PeDQOWvdkOS3qSQLjm5-3ZrtJO1/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to:

1. specify columns letters that you wont to extract.
2. set number of rows that you need to skip
3. rename columns

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('claim.xls', skiprows=range(1, 11), usecols = "C,E,G,J,N,R,V,Z,AD,AH,AL,AP,AT")
df.columns = ['Enc. ID', 'Post Date', 'Claim ID', 'Svc. Date', 'Procedure', 'Mod', 'Patient', 'Billed to', 'Adj.Charge', 'Payments', 'Value', 'A/R Balance', 'Age']
```

**Output:**

```
   Enc. ID           Post Date  Claim ID           Svc. Date Procedure  Mod            Patient          Billed to Adj.Charge Payments   Value A/R Balance   Age
0  41083.0 2019-12-12 12:00:00  167189.0 2019-12-11 12:00:00     99204  NaN    Smith, Susan L.  NOVITAS SOLUTIONS     280.00        -  280.00      280.00  15.0
1  41156.0 2019-12-16 12:00:00  167774.0 2019-12-13 12:00:00     99204   25   Hester, Joyce A.  NOVITAS SOLUTIONS     280.00        -  280.00      280.00  13.0
2  41187.0 2019-12-18 12:00:00  169213.0 2019-12-17 12:00:00     99396  NaN  RHODA, KATHLEEN M      TRICARE PRIME     270.00        -  270.00      270.00   9.0
```